# Can't start node server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have an almost-vanilla create-react-app (v2) app that I've attached an express server to, which acts as an API server and is proxied. Locally, I run `npm run dev`, since my package json scripts section is like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node server --exec nodemon",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build",
    "dev": "run-p server start"
  },
```

However, this doesn't work on Heroku if I make a Procfile with `web: npm run dev` since it tells me that run-p cannot be found. So instead I do `web: node server/index.js` (since my server file lives at `server/index.js`. However, this gives me the following error in Heroku logs:

`Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

I thought starting my server would serve everything, since it has this line:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Listening on localhost:3001'));
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: We'll need to see the part of `index.js` where you tell your server (likely `express`) to listen. It must use the port provided by the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: @Chris Added to OP

Comment: Yeah, as I said in my previous comment you can't run on whatever port you want on Heroku (and even if you could, port 3001 would be strange choice for production). Use the `PORT` environment variable. This will be routed to regular HTTP and HTTPS ports, so you can just go to `yourapp.herokuapp.com` without asking for a particular port, but you do need to _listen_ on the port you're given. See Hamza's answer below for details.

Comment: I added the port stuff, but now it's telling me 'Cannot GET /', with a 404 when it tries to load the page. I do have a postbuild script in my package.json, but it's apparently not building the right directory?

Comment: Do you have a route configured for `/`?

Comment: @Chris I do, yeah (`<Route path="/" exact component={Main} />`). I switched up the  express server for static files too, but in this mode I get errors like `manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.` and a bunch of 404s for chunk files not found...

Comment: That looks like a _front-end_ (probably React) route. But that only kicks in after the server sends the JavaScript to the browser. How are the routes set up on the _back-end_?

Comment: The only other routes I have in the server are `app.get` and `app.post` ones for api routes (`'/api/endpoint'`). This generic one is the only one I have for serving content.

Comment: Then that's why you're getting a 404 for `/`. Try requesting `/api` instead. Moving forward, you'll have to share more code. We can't do this all in comments. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Add this before app.listen:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));
```

Then instead of 3000 in app.listen, add this:

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => console.log('Listening on localhost:3001'));
```

This should work the same locally.